# Bootstrap 3.0 hidden-xs not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3.0 page that is divided like 9 cols on the left and 3 cols on the right now. What I want is to hide 3 right cols when screen size is less than 768. This is my code structure:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
     <div id="column_right">
   //php stuff goes here 
    </div>
 <div>
```

CSS is default bootstrap 3.0, but the problem is that when I go to small screen size like mobiles the right 3 cols are still visible. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Remove `col-xs-12`, it contradicts `hidden-xs`. Even still, the html is strange. The `row` is inside `col-....` when it is supposed to be the other way around.

Comment: sorry about that i typed it and it here and done by mistake

Comment: And if you remove `col-xs-12`? What's the point of it if you want the column hidden on xs screens?

Comment: It works fine with your markup, even tho previous commentator is right about that class being unnecessary. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6372/

Comment: @Cthulhu you can nest as many rows and columns beneath rows and columns. Just make sure whenever you add a .row, you also add a .col-x-x to offset the padding.

Comment: like @ganders said, your code seems to do what is should.

Answer (score 2):

Your markup pretty much works as it stands now. Here's a bootply [adding in your left column]

http://www.bootply.com/FYLVttbyUH

Here's the code in case bootply is not available:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 red">
  <div id="column_left">
    <span>This is always shown</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs blue">
  <div id="column_right">
    <span>This should be hidden on mobile devices</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div></div>


            <div id="push"></div>
```

Comment: Please include the code from your Bootply link in your answer, ensuring it'll be useful for users in the future should the link become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include 2 columns.

Maybe what you want is something like this?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <!-- persistent column -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
     <div class="row">
        <div id="column_right">
       //php stuff goes here 
        </div>
     </div>    
    </div> 
<div>
```

Comment: i do have that one on left side .

Comment: be careful adding a .row without a corresponding .col-x-x. Your padding on the row without the corresponding negative padding with the column will screw up the look...